# Surface area of L2 ball + L1 ball

Tags: geometry, analysis, volume, convex-geometry

Consider the L1-ball $A$ and the L2-ball $B$ in $d$-dimensions.
Consider the Minkowski sum $A+B$ of the two corresponding sets of points.
Is there a known expression for the Vol$(A+B)$ or the surface area of $A+B$?
Or, is there some interesting upper-bound on the quantities?

Answer (score 1):

You can exemplify by 3 dimensional case. The volume is sum of following terms

1. volume of A itself
2. for every face of A, product of area of face and radius of B
3. for every edge of A, product of length of edge and area of 1/4 circle with radius of B
4. for every vertex of A, volume of 1/8 sphere

So for dimension $n$, each $i$-face contributes product of volume of that surface multiplies volume of positive quadrant of unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^{n-i}$. And surface area are derivative of volume w.r.t radius of B